# es posible ejecutar stages con versiones diferentes de node en un Jenkinsfile

Tags: jenkins, groovy, devops

Buen dia comunidad, tengo el siguiente problema el stage install debe correr con la version de node 10.24.1 y el stage test debe correr con la version node 16.17.0, es posible en el siguiente jenkinsfile decirle a cada stage que me ejecute una version en especifico

```
pipeline {
        agent any
        tools {
            nodejs 'node:10.24.1'
        }
        stages {
            stage('install') {
                steps {
                    script{
                    sh """
                    cd front
                    npm install
                    """
                }
                }
            }
            stage('test') {
                steps {
                    script{
                    sh """
                    cd front
                    npm run test
                    """
                }
        }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Podrias pobrar de la siguiente forma:

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {
        stage('install') {
            environment {
                NODE_VERSION = '10.24.1'
            }
            tools {
                nodejs "${NODE_VERSION}"
            }
            steps {
                script{
                    sh """
                        cd front
                        npm install
                    """
                }
            }
        }
        stage('test') {
            environment {
                NODE_VERSION = '12.22.1'
            }
            tools {
                nodejs "${NODE_VERSION}"
            }
            steps {
                script{
                    sh """
                        cd front
                        npm run test
                    """
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Saludos